# Bug - float left starting from second element instead of start of div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a strange issue with floating elements. The float-left property of the heart is getting floated as if the start of the `div` is from bellow the add to bag button, instead of the start of the div on the very left, under the yellow box with 1 in it.

[image]

All three elements have `float-left` property, and their parent div has `clearfix` class from Bootstrap. I don't think any other CSS is acting upon their positioning.

**.html**

```
<div class="clearfix">
 <div class="pull-left">1 dropdown box</div>
 <div class="pull-left">add to bag button</div>
 <div class="pull-left">heart</div>
</div>
```

They are usually aligned next to each other, but on smaller screens the `add to bag` button pushes the heart button on the bottom line and the idea is when it gets pushed to be under the dropdown with the quantity.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is not a bug, is the native behaviour of floated elements.

Comment: If you need your element to be kind of responsive, so the heart will go to the right of the _add to bag_ button when he can, personally I always use `<ul></ul>` with `display : inline-block` for the childrens `<li></li>`.

Comment: Can't recreate it, please provide relevant CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/5qqqqmj8/ - something's pushing that heart right... :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use Breakpoint for the the small screen size that then use

```
poistion:relative;
```

in the css

```
@media screen max-width:480px;{
    position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use float (use `display:inline-block` instead) and it solves. If you want to use floats, you need to reestructure html. You can make a simple grid with classes to small and big screens, that allows you to control better the behaviour.